# Error: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I'm seeing the error:

```
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted
```

On my page. Based on some reading, I gather that the error can occur due to several reasons, a and can be quite difficult to troubleshoot.

On the aspx page I have two drop down controls:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsClients" DataTextField="Client_Name" DataValueField="Client_Name" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" ondatabound="DropDownList3_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddQualIDInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsQual" DataTextField="Project_Name" DataValueField="Qual_ID"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind file I use ajax to update and rebuild the second drop down option based on the selected value from the first drop down menu:

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dsQual.Where = "Client_Name = \"" + ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue +"\"";
}
```

The drop down get's per-populated sometimes, however mostly throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing your page (server side controls) dynamically and that would change `view state` of page so upon post-back, ASP.NET decrypts `view state` and that doesn't match expected one.

Comment: Remove any non-server-side control or explain what you need then we can help more.

Comment: I need to update the values in a drop down (ddQualIDInsert) using ajax based on the the value selected from another drop down (DropDownList3).

Comment: Then don't update it yourself from client side. Use a AJAX drop-down and trigger it to update itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue and it took me a long time to resolve it in my Code.

---

First thing is I had UpdatePanel and a jquery dialog. Below is the script I am using.

```
<script>
     var uiDialog = $('.ui-dialog-container').parent();
     (uiDialog.next().length && uiDialog.appendTo((document.forms.item(0) != null) ?   document.forms.item(0) : document.body));
     //verifyUser();
     function ShowDialog() {

         dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
             autoOpen: true,
             resizable: false,
             height: 400,
             width: 800,
             modal: true,
             overlay: {
                 backgroundColor: '#000',
                 opacity: 0.5
             }


         });
     }



</script>
```

This is the form

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Verify Transaction" style="display:none;" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"  />


            <fieldset style="background-color:#ffd800;border-radius:5px;">

            <label for="fname">First Name    :</label>
            <label for="fname"><%= DetailsView1.Rows[7].Cells[1].Text %></label><br />

            <label for="lname">Last Name     :</label>
            <label for="lname"><%= DetailsView1.Rows[9].Cells[1].Text %></label><br />

            <label for="zip">Zip Code        :</label>
            <label for="zip"><%= DetailsView1.Rows[22].Cells[1].Text %></label><br />



            </fieldset>
    <hr />
    <asp:Button id="btnVerified" runat="server" OnClick="btnVerify_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Verified" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancelled" runat="server" OnClientClick="dialog.dialog('close')" Text="Cancelled" UseSubmitBehaviour="false"/>


</div>
```

Here we see that I am using server side and client side script in the  Button Control. The important thing for both of them to work is remove the form tag from the dialog , put the script in UpdatePanel and set UseSubmitBehaviour="false". This will cause the dialog to postback which is what we need to go to server-side.

Initially I had form tags. Once I removed the form tag it executed both the events OnClientClick and OnClick server side events executed. Cheers !! If any body has this issue here is the solution.

Following issues got finally resolved :

1. Client-Side Event execution.
2. Server-Side Event execution with jQuery-UI dialog pop-up.
3. Dialog doing a PostBack which means that we can have a complete ASP.NET Form with Controls inside the dialog.
4. The issue of 'state information invalid for this page and might be corrupted' got resolved.

Note : I am using DetailsView Control inside the form.

Cheers !!